# Stop an href # from jumping to top of page

Tags: css, href

I have an accordion on my page, but when I click one of the tabs the page jumps to the top of the accordion. At the moment there is no jquery controlling the animation it's all CSS. Is there a way to stop this?

```
          <section id="contact">

            <h2><a href="#contact">Contact</a></h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </p>

          </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try preventing default behaviour, with `event.preventDefault()`

```
<h2><a href="#contact" class="PartOfAccordion">Contact</a></h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.PartOfAccordion').click( function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if "*At the moment there is no jquery controlling the animation it's all CSS.*" implies he does not have jQuery included.

Comment: You could be correct. Your solution is more elegant for OP :)

Comment: +1 for you anyways! Who builds an accordion without jQuery.. don't forget `<script></script>` tags :)

Comment: Very true indeed! Thanks Dan! (OP, if you're not wanting to use jQuery, please accept Dans answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have jQuery or simply want to use a quick Javascript:

```
<h2><a href="#contact" onclick="return false;">Contact</a></h2>
```