# Why does my javascript-code to hide/show div-boxes not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide/show the main-contentholders on my website based on what menu-option the reader clicks on. This seems like a simple thing to me, I've done it multiple times before but now it just won't work. My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title id="titel">Mercedes F1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mercedes.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1">
<script>
function sidbyte(p){
var p;
if(p == 1) {
document.getElementById("forare").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("mercedes").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("statistik").style.display = "none";
}
else if(p == 2) {
document.getElementById("forare").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("mercedes").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("statistik").style.display = "none";
}
else if(p == 3) {
document.getElementById("forare").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("mercedes").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("statistik").style.display = "block";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
<nav>
<a href="" onclick="sidbyte(1)">Förarbiografi</a>
<img src="Media/Menu_icon.svg" class="menuicon" alt="MenuIcon">
<a href="" onclick="sidbyte(2)">Mercedes F1</a>
<img src="Media/Menu_icon.svg" class="menuicon" alt="MenuIcon">
<a href="" onclick="sidbyte(3)">Statistik</a>
</nav>
<div id="forare" class="main">
<h1 class="rubrik">Förare</h1>
<p>

</p>
</div>
<div id="mercedes" class="main">
<h1 class="rubrik">Mercedes F1 genom åren</h1>
<p>

</p>
</div>
<div id="statistik" class="main">
<h1 class="rubrik">Statistik</h1>
<p>

</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you already taken a look into the error console of your browser?

Comment: it's working. http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/4Lj7j4p4/

Comment: @Ashad Strange, it does not work at me. I copy the code and put it on a local file. There did it not work.

Comment: Here is a better way of doing it. ---> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLzqud5n/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that whenever you are clicking on the ***a*** tag the page reloads. So put ***#*** inside the ***href*** attributes of the ***a*** tags. Thats it.

```
<a href="#">Click Here</a>
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/4Lj7j4p4/)

***Note :*** The local ***p*** declared inside the function is of no use as you are using the parameter. So better you remove that if you are only using the parameter, though it doesn't effect your code unless you refer to that with ***this*** keyword. Like,

```
this.p // refers to the local p you declared.
```

Comment: Yes I could fix at my try

Comment: Preventing default click event will work better than navigating to `#` on each click, so `return false;` in the end of the `sidbyte` function is far a better way. Additionally, `this.p` will refer to `window.p` (a.k.a. globally defined variable), which doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: But in that case you'll have to remove the href attribute also. That'll make your anchor tags appear like text.

Comment: @AshadShanto It doesn't matter what you have in `href` attributes if the default event is prevented: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lj7j4p4/4/.

Comment: Ohh, that's my mistake. Didn't returned the returned value from the function inside onclick.

Comment: Just a note, `var p` still declares a global, but I think JS is smart enough to not overwrite an existing variable when declaring one without a value. Also, if it were `let p`, that would be confined to the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading the page each time the action is triggered, so the default state is returned, meaning that the transformation is no longer applied. By giving the `<a>` tag an `href` of `#` or `javascript:void(0);`, you can prevent the page refresh. Or even better, you can actually execute the JS from the `href` itself.

I actually recommend using `javascript:void(0);`, since it doesn't jump to the top of the page by default, while `#` does. However, that behavior [can be prevented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738729/stop-an-href-from-jumping-to-top-of-page) with a simple `onclick="return false"`.

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/caffeinewriter/pen/emvmqM)

Answer (score -2):

Find the below code which i did using jQuery. It's very short and easy to understand.

HTML

```
<div class="page">
  <nav>
    <a class="one" href="#">Förarbiografi</a>
      <img src="Media/Menu_icon.svg" class="menuicon" alt="MenuIcon">
    <a class="two" href="#">Mercedes F1</a>
      <img src="Media/Menu_icon.svg" class="menuicon" alt="MenuIcon">
    <a class="three" href="#">Statistik</a>
  </nav>

  <div id="forare" class="main">
    <h1 class="rubrik">Förare</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="mercedes" class="main">
    <h1 class="rubrik">Mercedes F1 genom åren</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
  <div id="statistik" class="main">
    <h1 class="rubrik">Statistik</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.one').click(function(){
    $('.main').hide();
    $('#forare').show();
});
$('.two').click(function(){
    $('.main').hide();
    $('#mercedes').show();
});
$('.three').click(function(){
    $('.main').hide();
    $('#statistik').show();
});
```

CSS

```
.main{
    display:none;
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/65shrus5/)**

Comment: Maybe there are some circumstances, so the OP can't use Jquery.

Comment: He was asking what was wrong with his code, not a better way to do that.

Comment: @shanidkv If it's not already included, jQuery adds substantial unnecessary bloat, all for a few lines of syntactic sugar. Not to mention, jQuery is usually slower than using the included functions, in my experience.